# how to configure xmlrpc-c abyss server host?

Tags: c++, xml-rpc

I am using xmlrpc-c library (c++ version) to write a program. I find that there is no way to configure the xmlrpc server's host. I can only configure the port like below. Can anyone tell me how to configure the hostname for this server?

```
xmlrpc_c::registry myRegistry;
xmlrpc_c::defaultMethodPtr const XMLRPCMethodP(handler);
//myRegistry.addMethod("method", XMLRPCMethodP);
myRegistry.setDefaultMethod(XMLRPCMethodP);
webServer = new serverAbyss(xmlrpc_c::serverAbyss::constrOpt()
                            .registryP(&myRegistry)
                            .logFileName("/tmp/xmlrpc_log")
                            .portNumber(8183)
                            .uriPath("/")
                            );  // Currently, there is no way to configure Host here.

try {
    webServer->run();
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a server, so it *listens* for connections on the given port on the machine you are running it on. Giving it a hostname does not make much sense. You can, of course, specify a host to connect to on the client, see [here](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/doc/libgeneral++.html). Or you are talking about binding the server to a particular network interface? I don't think the library supports that.

#### Edit 0:

I think you should be able to use the `socketFd` and `socketBound` options if you need to listen on given interface - create your own socket, bind it to whatever, pass it to the API. That's just from looking at their source, so I have no idea if this actually works.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually I read the page of your link before. But it seems that the document didn't say about what is connectIt and how to use it, do you have some example of using the connectIt?

Comment: Ugh, that looks like some not-really-up-to-date-docs. Just go with the examples that use service URLs. Is that a problem for you?

Comment: Actually, I am talking about biding the server to a particular network interface.